# Iron router Meteor.user() isn't ready

Tags: meteor, meteorite, atmosphere, iron-router

The problem I'm facing is that my `userId` function is running before `Meteor.user()` is ready, therefore there is no `Meteor.user()._id` present and thus I get `Exception in defer callback: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined` when I run the code. If I use the command `Meteor.userId()`, it fixes it for that part, but it doesn't solve the big issue being that `Meteor.user()` isn't ready.

Here's my code:

```
userId : function(){
  console.log('userId called and here is the Meteor.user(): ', Meteor.user());
  return (this.params._id || Meteor.user()._id);
},
waitOn: function () {
  console.log('waitOn called');
  return Meteor.subscribe('userProfile', this.userId())
},
addedData : function(){
  ........
},
data: function(){
  ...........
},
onBeforeAction : function(){
  ............
},
onStop : function(){
  _.each(this.subscriptions, function(sub){
    sub.stop();
  });
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: can't you just use `Meteor.userId()` directly in `waitOn`?

Comment: Replacing `this.userId()` with `Meteor.userId()` fixes it in `waitOn`. Thanks @ChristianFritz